# arduino uno how to adjust the servo motor angle with a metal sensor

Tags: arduino

How can I adjust the servo motor angle when metal is detected by the metal sensor in this code?

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  Serial.println(sensorValue);

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: What's metal sensor? what pin it's connected to? To what angle?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the [Servo](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/servo/) library, chech out the page and follow the samples, it should be real easy. Note the motor power supply issue, many beginners fail with that.